# Angular 2 select editable

Tags: angular2-forms

I have a simple select like this:

```
<select [style]="{width : '100%' }" [(ngModel)]="rule.valoreImmesso" class="lm-custom-dropdown">
      <option *ngFor="let valore of rule.comboValues" [value]="valore.value">{{valore.label}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to add an input text inside the dropdown in order to filter the options. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: I need same. I need editable multi select combobox in angular 2/typescript..which must also support keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<input type="text" list="cars" [(ngModel)]="rule.valoreImmesso"/>
<datalist id="cars">
  <option *ngFor="let valore of rule.comboValues" [value]="valore.value"></option>
</datalist>
```

But `datalist` tag not supported in **Safari** So you must write a custom dropdown on your own. You can find some in the internet and modify them as you desired.